# ¿Porqué obtengo este error en MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estuve realizando mi modelado de datos en MySQLWorkbench, lo guardé y todo normal.

Pero, una vez lo abrí nuevamente, me apareció este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cerrar el mensaje, se abre mi archivo pero vacío, es decir, no aparece ninguna tabla.

Solo tengo un archivo `.bak` pero no sé como restaurarlo.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia y ayuda

Comment: ¿Has arrancado el servidor MySQL? ¿Has borrado las tablas del servidor MySQL? Por favor, copia y pega los mensajes que aparecen en el archivo de registro, allí habrá más información acerca del problema (si la conexión fue rechazada, si la tabla no se encontró, etc).